# Is there a scrollbar/scrollviewer property that knows if there is enough content to scroll or not?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, scrollbar, scrollviewer

The reason that I ask is that I want to be able to change the arrow colors to a gray / faded / disabled looking color if you can't actually scroll the content. I'm assuming I can use a DataTrigger on the element's property to change the colors based on whether or not the scrollbars are actually scrollable.

I apologize if this information is somewhere obvious. Perhaps I don't know how to word the search correctly.

[image: No content]

[image: Scrollable content]

Comment: Why not just have Visisbility = Automatic so there is no scroll bar if it does not need to scroll?

Comment: @Frisbee my problem is, if the scrollbar is not present then the content looks odd. Granted, this is a problem with my styling for the listbox items, but I'm looking for multiple ways to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I would of thought you could compare the ScrollableHeight Property to the ViewportHeight... But its easier just have the ScollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility set to Auto and not show it